# gridfs mongodb and php script

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a php script who inserts documents in gridfs.
in this DB i have 1346214 document.
when i run this script for adding 10500 document i have this error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to   connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: Cannot assign requested address' in /root/upload.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /root/upload.php(5): Mongo->__construct('127.0.0.1:27017')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /root/upload.php on line 5
```

in mongod.log i have this message

```
2014-05-08T12:24:13.537+0200 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57221 #93806 (63 connections now open)
2014-05-08T12:24:13.538+0200 [conn93806]  authenticate db: uniform_server { authenticate: 1, user: "user", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2014-05-08T12:24:13.538+0200 [conn93806] Failed to authenticate user@uniform_server with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user@uniform_server
2014-05-08T12:24:13.538+0200 [conn93806] end connection 127.0.0.1:57221 (62 connections now open)
```

have you any idea about this problem?

Thanks

Comment: where is your upload.php???

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of the php script and i run it 10500 via this command                  for i in {1..10500..1}; do php upload.php;  done

```
    <?php

    $conn = new Mongo("127.0.0.1:27017");         // Connect
    $db = $conn->uniform_server;                // Select DB
    $db->authenticate("user","passwd");        // Authenticate to MongoDB
    $grid = $db->getGridFS();                    // Initialize GridFS
    $tab_pj = array("document0.pdf",
                    "document1.tif",
                    "document2.doc",
                    "document3.png",
                    "document4.JPG",
                    "document5.xls",
                    "document6.rar", 
                    "document7.ppt",
                    "document8.rtf"
                    );
    $pj_id = rand(0,8);                 
    $name = $tab_pj[0];        // Get Uploaded file name
    $id = $grid->storeFile($name);    // Store uploaded file to GridFS

    $conn->close();  // Close connection

    exit(0);
?>
```